# Can I use PowerDNS as a HTTP Load Balancer?

Tags: load-balancing, powerdns

I would like to serve multiple web applications and make them available via domain names inside of a test network. Therefore I would like to to use PowerDNS because it seems to have a good API. The web applications will be accessed by a small cluster of crawlers.

I picture to run the same web application with the same domain name on two servers for load balancing. Can PowerDNS point to the server with less load or do I need another piece of software to achieve this? What do I need to look for? Something like "HTTP Load balancer"? And how would such a software work together with the DNS?

Comment: Be careful wether client-side (or in-between) caching will help or hurt you. I would not recommend using DNS-Load-Balancing if you have any sort of session on your web app. If nothing will brake if one client gets the html page from server A, the css from server B, the JavaScript from server C and the image from server D then you are probably OK.

I don't know if PowerDNS is capable of what you are looking for, but i'm optimistic. Maybe search for keepalived integration with PowerDNS.

Comment: I serve static pages for now. Therefore it doesn't matter if the contents of one page comes from different servers. BUT I'm interested in a solution that would also work with sessions because that is the more likely/general case.

Comment: What you want is called a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) or [load-balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)). HAproxy, Nginx, Pound and Apache all offer some of the features you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me to [read about the different Load Balancing solutions](https://www.maxcdn.com/blog/haproxy-load-balancing/) (DNS, Hardware, Software).
Thank you Silent-Bob for pointing out that the sessions should be considered.